# A question about using Squeeze Theorem to solve theoretical convergence question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Could you give me some hint how to deal with this question:

Suppose $a_n\le b_n \le c_n$ for almost all n, $b_n\to L$, $c_n-a_n\to 0$.
Prove: $a_n \to L,b_n \to L$.

Well, if $a_n\to a, b_n \to b$ and $c_n-a_n\to 0$, than $a=b$ and from Squeeze Theorem we can conclude a=b=L.

So, we need to prove that this is only possible case.

$a_n$ is bounded above by L, so it could not converge to $+\infty$,
$b_n$ is bounded below by L, so it could not converge to $-\infty$.

if $c_n-a_n\to 0$ it is not possible that $a_n\to $ some finite number and $b_n \to +\infty$ 
or  $b_n\to $ some finite number and $a_n \to -\infty$.

I failed to eliminate the possibility of $a_n \to -\infty$ and $b_n \to +\infty$,
and the possibility of $a_n,b_n$ do not have any limit at all.

Thanks.

Comment: One can split into very similar cases. For infinitely many $n$ we have (i) a_n\le L$ and $c_n\le L$ **or** (ii) a_n\le L$ and $c_n\ge L$ **or** (two more). Note that the "ors" are not exclusive, for example both (i) and (ii) could happen for infinitely many $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $0\leq b_n-a_n\leq c_n-a_n$.  Hence by the squeeze thm, $b_n-a_n\rightarrow 0$.  Now apply the triangle inequality:  $|a_n-L|\leq |a_n-b_n|+|b_n-L|$.  Everything on the RHS goes to 0, implying a_n converges to L.  The other case is similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you made a typo and actually have $c_n\rightarrow L$. You can prove $a_n\rightarrow L$ by using the triangle equality: $|a_n-L|\le|a_n-c_n|+|c_n-L|$. Then you can apply the squeeze theorem.